# Android uses SymbolLayer to create thousands of layers for display

Tags: android

```
 private fun addLayer(layer: MapBoxParams.Layer) { var sourceLayer = symbolLayer(layer.layerId!!, layer.sourceId!!) { iconImage(layer.iconImage!!) iconSize(layer.iconSize!!) textColor(layer.textColor!!) textAnchor(layer.textAnchor!!) textOffset(layer.textOffset!!) textIgnorePlacement(false) textAllowOverlap(false) textField(Expression.get(layer.title!!)) textSize(10.0) filter(has( literal(layer.title!!))) } }
```

I created thousands of layers using the above code through GeoJson, but the number of layers displayed on the Android device and iOS device is different at the same zoom level. How should I set it

Can we achieve the same display quantity as IOS through settings